# Convert timestamps from a dataframe column to date format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

The following data frame is the result of

```
top5 = df.nlargest(5,columns='B',keep='all')
```

```
          A      B        C          D           E      F     G     H    I
77 2013-08-17  42302  2278503  100644.38  5021507.24  72471  5729  5729  217
70 2013-08-10  42245  2016000  103374.87  4492859.82  69996  5567  5567  223
74 2013-08-14  42226  2154625   78504.31  4766845.59  71481  1727  1727  219
66 2013-08-06  42086  1871575   81608.23  4209532.51  68744  1778  1778  222
59 2013-07-30  42032  1611459   79312.12  3691785.45  65855  1701  1701  237
```

I would like to print only dates as my result. I've tried something like this to print only the `A` column:

```
print(top5['A'].values.tolist())
```

But it gives me this result:

```
[1376697600000000000, 1376092800000000000, 1376438400000000000, 1375747200000000000, 1375142400000000000]
```

But I need a result like:

```
[2013-08-17,2013-08-10,2013-08-14,2013-08-06,2013-07-30]
```

What's the way to convert this timestamp to date format?

Comment: what about `print(top5['A'])`? or if the column is of dtype datetime (which I'd assume), `print(top5['A'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`? Btw. what you get from `print(top5['A'].values.tolist())` is POSIX timestamps with nanosecond resolution - that's how datetimes are handled internally.

Comment: This is perfect as a dataframe output. But I'm looking for something to store in list. When i store this value in separate list it convert into timestamp format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get a list of strings from a datetime column, use

```
import pandas as pd

# what you have is like
top5  = pd.DataFrame({'A': pd.to_datetime(['2013-08-17', '2013-08-10', '2013-08-14'])})
# note the column A is of dtype datetime

# format to string using strftime and then cast to_list():
l_A = top5['A'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').to_list()
# l_A
# ['2013-08-17', '2013-08-10', '2013-08-14']
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the column in list().

```
print(list(top5['A'].astype('datetime64[ns]')))
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's the square brackets and not the `.astype('datetime64[ns]')` that is the major difference?

Comment: Both actually, — .astype('datetime64[ns]') — make sure that the date format is yyyy-mm-dd. Whereas [ ] will make sure that the output will be printed horizontally and not vertically.

Comment: Sorry my bad, you actually need to enclose it in list() and not in bracket.